# Travis build - Unable to retrieve secret key from key ring file as it does not exist

Tags: android, git, encryption, gradle, travis-ci

I currently use Travis CI for my open source project. All went well till I tried to upload an artifact to Maven Central staging repository once the travis build was successful.

Please find the steps i followed below:

- Added a initiate-publish.sh script file which will publish to Maven central after build is successful.
- Encrypted the following

  - Encryption password to secure my secring file -> travis encrypt -r  username/gitrepo ENCRYPT_PASSWORD="my password"
  - secring.gpg file - openssl aes-256-cbc -in .utility/local.secring.gpg -out .utility/secring.gpg.enc -pass pass:"my password"
    -> This generated secring.gpg.enc which i added to my repository
- Modfied .travis.yml file with the following

  - before_install:
    openssl aes-256-cbc -pass pass:$ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD -in .utility/secring.gpg.enc -out .utility/local.secring.gpg -d

I committed the files to Git which triggered a build. 
The after_success: exits with an error stating
"Could not evaluate onlyIf predicate for task ':android-db-migration-library:signArchives'.

> Unable to retrieve secret key from key ring file '/home/travis/build/PalomaMobile/android-db-migration/android-db-migration-library/.utility/local.secring.gpg' as it does not exist"

You can view the logs https://travis-ci.org/PalomaMobile/android-db-migration/builds/63114335

From what i understand, the "before install" will decrypt the file and store it and my release script can access it.

Could you please help me understand why this happens. You can view my .travis.yml file, release script file etc.. @ https://github.com/PalomaMobile/android-db-migration

Comment: Hi, can you try adding a command at the end of your `before_install` step that prints the absolute path of the file? e.g. `find $PWD | grep "local.secring.gpg"`. This way you can compare with the path from the error message. If it's the same it maybe because Travis CI is removing the file somehow after the 'before_install' step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I double-checked your build log and it seems that your `signArchive` task is expecting the secret key to be located in

`/home/travis/build/PalomaMobile/android-db-migration/android-db-migration-library/.utility/generated.secring.gpg`

but in fact it is located in

`/home/travis/build/PalomaMobile/android-db-migration/.utility/generated.secring.gpg`

So I would suggest using an absolute path to the key file instead of a relative one in your `.utility/initiate-publish.sh` file.

Hope this helps!